# Azure Pipelines Deployment Group vs Deployment Pool

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines, azure-devops-deploymentgroups

I would like to know what the difference is between an Azure Pipeline Deployment Group and Deployment Pool. Equally importantly, under what circumstances or criteria would I choose either? Thanks.

Comment: Deployment Group and Deployment Pool are pretty much the same thing.  Does below answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Both of `Deployment Group` and `Deployment Pool` are logical sets of deployment target machines. The difference between them would be Deployment Group is used to manage the deployment targets in Project scope, and Deployment Pool is used to manage the deployment targets in the organization scope. Actually they are pretty much the same thing.

If you have a group of deployment targets you want to share it amongst your projects. You can choose to create a `Deployment pool` in the organization setting page. And check the projects you want provision this deployment pool.

When the deployment pool is provisioned to these selected projects. You will see a corresponding deployment group is created automatically in the these projects with the same deployment targets inside.

[image]

If the group of deployment targets is specific for one project. You can choose to create a  deployment group in the `Deployment groups` hub in this project.

Actually when this deployment group is created in the project scope. A corresponding deployment pool will be created automatically in the `Deployment pools` section in organization settings page. You can then share it amongst your other projects

Check document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops) for more information.